# Supported orientations not limiting actual orientations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an iPad game that I only want to see in landscape view. I have selected the landscape view from the target's summary and have the code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

in my first viewcontroller which is added to a navController. But the only effect that I can see by changing the target's orientations is not how it can be rotated but rather what direction it is first loaded in.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: Its interesting, that works on like 90% of my viewcontrollers, but for some reason just one of them it locks in landscape mode, but it wont allow it to rotate 180° if i turn it over... thoughts?